# Salesforce CMS Search Rest API Cannot Work

Tags: rest-api, rest, rest-service

We got an error about CMS search by Rest API

We run this url in workbench, always report ***errorCode: MISSING_ARGUMENT message: Specify a Library.***
/services/data/v57.0/connect/cms/items/search?contentSpaceOrFolderIds=***9Pu780000004XXXXXX***&page=1&pageSize=20&queryTerm=test&scope=All

Here is the link about CMS search document
https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.chatterapi.meta/chatterapi/connect_resources_cms_items_search.htm

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Should add 0Zu Ids together
/services/data/v57.0/connect/cms/items/search?contentSpaceOrFolderIds=***0Zu780000008XXXXXX,9Pu780000004XXXXXX***&queryTerm=1

Worked now
[image]